# I have more than one error getting from my php code connecting to my server

Tags: php, database

Errors are Warning:

> mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user
>   'test'@'10.1.1.23' (using password: YES) in
>   /home/a4228948/public_html/imageid.php on line 9
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid
>   MySQL-Link resource in /home/a4228948/public_html/imageid.php on line
>   10
>
> Warning: mysql_close(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link
>   resource in /home/a4228948/public_html/imageid.php on line 29

```
<?PHP

    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
    $user_name = "test";
    $password = "protection";
    $database = "temp";
    $server = "mysql6.000webhost.com";

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

    if ($db_found) {

    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM test";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);

    while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

    print $db_field['id'] ;

    }

    mysql_close($db_handle);

    }
    else {

    print "Database NOT Found ";
    mysql_close($db_handle);

    }
?>
```

Comment: It seems either the username (or) password is wrong. Try to login manually with these credentials and see whether it is allowing.

Comment: It is clear that the server property is pointing to another database server than has your username and password. Just try to use `localhost` for the server. i.e `$server = 'localhost'`

Comment: [This extension (mysql_*) is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)

Answer (score 1):

Error in Your Username or Password.
You check database **Username** and **Password** is correct . and server value set **localhost**

Answer (score 1):

Only first error is really important at this point, the rest could be fine, but at the line 9 you won't connect, so nothing more be done with the DB.

Please double check that case is right etc. (depending on MySQL settings DB name can be case sensitive too), and that there are no extra spaces (happened to me a few times when copy-pasting).

Check that the DB actually exists (via phpMyAdmin or whatever your provider uses).

Answer (score 0):

Check `Database_name`, `Hostname` and Login credentials (`Username` ans `password`) In term of case sensitive, spelling etc.

If you have correct `credentials`,  `database_name` and  `Hostname` then 
check permission of user and grant permission.

Try

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

This is how I create my "Super User" privileges (although I would normally specify a host).
IMPORTANT NOTE

While this answer can solve the problem of access, WITH GRANT OPTION creates a MySQL user that can [edit the permissions of other users.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_grant-option)

The GRANT OPTION privilege enables you to give to other users or remove from other users those privileges that you yourself possess.

For security reasons, you should not use this type of user account for any process that the public will have access to (i.e. a website). It is recommended that you create a user with only database privileges for that kind of use.

```
grant all privileges on mydb.* to myuser@'%' identified by 'mypasswd';
grant all privileges on mydb.* to myuser@localhost identified by 'mypasswd';
```

**Warning 2 -**

Change

```
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);
```

to

```
$db_found  = mysql_select_db($database_spyware, $db_handle) || die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Actually problems with the server side permissions, Anyway thanks for your help..